# Intern with Phantomjs GhostDriver

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, intern

I'm trying to setup Intern to run with PhantomJS on a Windows 7 machine

Since now my setup is as follows:

demo test `root/unit/tests/phantom.js`:

```
define([
    'intern!object',
    'intern/chai!assert'
], function(registerSuite, assert) {

registerSuite({
    name: 'PhantomTest',

    'dummy': function () {
        assert(true, "Works!");
    }

});

});
```

Configuration file `root/unit/intern.config.js`:

```
define({

proxyPort: 9000,

proxyUrl: 'http://localhost:9000/',

capabilities: {
    'selenium-version': '2.30.0'
},

environments: [
    {
      browserName: 'phantom'
    }
],
maxConcurrency: 3,

useSauceConnect: false,

webdriver: {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 4444
},

// used here
loader: {
},

suites: [ 'unit/tests/phantom.js' ],


functionalSuites: [ /* 'myPackage/tests/functional' */ ],


excludeInstrumentation: /^tests\//
});
```

By running this test and config in a browser it just works.

To run Intern with PhantomJS i execute:

```
phantomjs --webdriver=4444
```

And:

```
cd root
node node_modules\intern\runner.js config=unit/intern.config
```

The console running Phantomjs then returns:

```
[INFO  - 2013-07-01T21:29:07.253Z] SessionManagerReqHand - _postNewSessionCommand - New Session Created: 42ba5b50-e295-11e2-86f7-e331eb8b922d
```

While the other one outputs the following message without any further log:

```
Defaulting to "runner" reporter
Listening on 0.0.0.0:9000
Initialised phantomjs 1.9.1 on windows-7-32bit
```

Any hint on what i'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this is https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10522; phantomjs is using an extremely old version of JavaScriptCore that has no `Function.prototype.bind`. Your best bet at this moment is to switch to using the `geezer` version of Intern, which should work properly in this older environment.

Comment: I've managed to make it work.

1st of all i've downloaded and installed the geezer branch as you suggested, but nothing changed.
Then i played a bit with the `suites` paths and discovered that the starting point in resolving `'unit/tests/phantom.js'` was the `node_modules/intern` folder.
Changing suites paths to '../../unit/tests/phantom.js' worked.

Same stuff happens with Selenium with both firefox and chrome, didn't test on IE.

Comment: You should not include '.js' at the end of an AMD module identifier; this makes the loader think you are trying to load a plain JS file, not an AMD module, which bypasses some of the path resolution code. However, I’ll make sure someone checks to make sure there is not also a bug in geezer branch.

Comment: Silly mistake :( by removing `.js` the `'unit/tests/phantom'` path works. Thanx for the support and sorry for the inconvenience.